# Difference between root account and administrative account

Tags: sudo, root

If a user with administrative privilege can have all the powers of root using `sudo` ,
then what is the advantage of having root account?

Comment: A typical usage is system maintenance possibly when you need a system recovery. For instance, when you select the "recovery mode" to boot from the Grub menu.

Comment: Isn't not having to use `sudo` an advantage?  Note that having "all the powers of root" is not quite the same as being root, since the root user can take those powers away, but no one can take them from root.

Comment: Thank you everybody for help! Barun, goldlocks, slm, and  Joseph R. Marking it as solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Disabling root

You have to have a root account. The only things you can do with it, in terms of "disabling" it, are:

1. Lock the account

   ```
   $ sudo passwd -l root
   ```
2. Give root an unusable password

   ```
   $ sudo usermod -p '!' root
   ```

#### sudo - as user root

Remember that when a user with "administrative privileges" is making use of `sudo` they're running commands with elevated privileges as the user root!

You can see that this is true with a simple `ps` command:

```
$ sudo sh -c "ps -eaf | grep [s]udo"
root      2625 26757  0 04:19 pts/10   00:00:00 sudo sh -c ps -eaf | grep [s]udo
```

The above shows that when the `ps` command is executed, you're effectively the user root.

#### Booting

Also when booting into a system in single user mode (from GRUB), you'll need to login using the root account. Typically you're passing either the word `single` to GRUB or the number `1`.

#### What sudo permissions do I have?

On a system where one has been given `sudo` permissions you can use the command `sudo -l` to see what rights you do have. These are not a complete set of everyone's rights, just the user that's running the command.

For example:

```
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for saml on this host:
    env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG
    LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME
    LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY",
    secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User saml may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) ALL
    (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/bluetooth, (root) /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/cpu-control, (root)
    /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/resolutions, (root) /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/rotate, (root) /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/touchpad, (root)
    /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/vga-out, (root) /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/wifi
```

**NOTE:** The commands one's been granted access to are everything after the line, "User saml may run the following ....".

#### Limiting access via sudo

Sudo has a fairly rich facility for limiting access to specific commands, groups of commands, specific users, and/or specific groups of users. There are some caveats however with `sudo`.

You can grant full access to everything with this line in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
aaditya      ALL=(ALL)    ALL
```

You could also give a user what appears to be simple access to `vim` certain files:

```
aaditya      ALL=/usr/bin/vim
```

This would be a huge mistake however, since many editors such as `vim` allow you to invoke a subshell from within them. So the user `aaditya` would be able to gain access to a shell with root permissions, even if the `sudo` permissions didn't intend for that to happen.

Comment: At college I am using RHEL v5, and I have a sudo account (added myself to /etc/sudoers), but I cant run administrative commands like adduser( sudo adduser - gives output adduser: command not found). But when the system admin logins as root , he can perform the adduser command. So if using sudo gives me same privileges as root, why cant I perform the adduser command?

Comment: @AadityaBagga - it's not giving you the same permissions as root, it's giving access to run certain commands *AS* root! If you're able to add yourself to `/etc/sudoers`, then you're likely able to do whatever you want. Adding a line such as this to `/etc/sudoers`: `aaditya ALL=(ALL)  ALL` will grant you carte blanche access to do anything *AS* root.

Comment: I added myself to /etc/sudoers by requesting the sysadmin to let me access the root account using su. I thought that if I added myself to sudoers I could perform administrative commands but I cant!

Comment: @AadityaBagga - if you have `su` access to root then you can do anything you want through that as well. A `sudo -l` is still the best way to see what your account has been granted, officially. There are always cracks 8-).

Comment: @slm..I dont have access to su! I requested the sysadmin to open a terminal with su so that I could add myself to the sudoers list in order to perform administrative commands, but I am not able to, as I have mentioned earlier. So perhaps there is a difference between the root account and an administrator added to /etc/sudoers.

Answer (score 2):

An administrative account and `root` are by no means the same. Other than what goldilocks and slm mentioned you should also know that `root` can significantly limit what the `sudo` user is allowed to do on `root`'s behalf (see `man sudoers` for examples). This is especially useful when a senior sysadmin wants to delegate some administration tasks to a junior admin without granting them full access. After all, a user with full `sudo` access can hijack the `root` account.